# AWK - sum row, columns x to y and print as new column

Tags: awk

I have a file that has say 50 columns. I want to sum columns 10 to 50, since columns 1-9 have text data. I want to include every column in the output and the final column is the sum.

I can do this using a very long statement:

```
awk '{X=$0}{split(X,x)}{print X , x[10]+x[11]+x[12]+x[13]+x[14]+x[15]+x[16]+x[17]+x[18]+x[19]+x[20]+x[21]+x[22]+x[23]+x[24]+x[25]+x[26]+x[27]+x[28]+x[29]+x[30]+x[31]+x[32]+x[33]+x[34]+x[35]+x[36]+x[37]+x[38]+x[39]+x[40]+x[41]+x[42]+x[43]+x[44]+x[45]+x[46]+x[47]+x[48]+x[49]+x[50]}' input > output
```

I was wondering how I could go about cleaning this up? This works fine, but is very slow on my large files.

(also, I have another awk oneliner I'm running after this to drop all columns where the sum is < 1000 using `awk '($51 > 999 )'`, can I combine this into the above?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown attempts only, since no samples are given so its not tested(this includes both of OP's shown attempts), this also considers that your field are space delimited.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  sum=0
  for(i=10;i<=NF;i++){ sum+=$i       }
  if(sum>999)        { print $0,sum  }
}' Input_file
```

Comment: This works really well! Thank you. I modified the script to not skip over the first line since I don't actually have a header. This outputs exactly what I want, but doesn't have a sum column (ie only has colums 1-50, but not the sum column 51.)

Comment: @Blaze9, sure, added edited solution as per your need, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@RavinderSingh13's script can be simplified to

```
$ awk '{NF++; for(i=10;i<NF;i++) $NF+=$i} $NF>999' file
```

Comment: That would cause awk to re-construct `$0` 40 times per input line (each time you change `$NF`) which would be relatively slow.